# Why do some places have rain frequently?

Tags: meteorology, precipitation, climatology

There are some places on Earth which holds the record of being "The wettest place on Earth". On what factors these places differ from other normal places?

An example of wettest place on Earth is [Cherrapunji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherrapunji)

PS: Normal places doesn't include deserts.

Comment: "The factors that differ" change wildly depending on what places you are comparing. You might want to narrow this question down to two places, something like Cherrapunji and Bejing (just an example).

Comment: @hichris123 "The factors which make those places wettest place". I don't know whether I got your point but I just asked as I understood the topic.

Comment: I am not sure why my question is being voted to close? I am simply asking here what makes those places special to have rain frequently compare to other normal places. I didn't get how come this is broad too.

Comment: As you can see from the first answer, the complete answer to your question would require the inclusion of every large-scale, regional and local effect related to precipitation. That is the reason it is "too broad".

Comment: As @aretxabaleta says, this is simply too broad. Please narrow down your question to comparing two different places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The factors contributing to such differences between any given 2 locations are simply too numerous to be specific. From the top of my head : Hadley cell, local topography, source of humidity upstream (oceans, lakes, ...), etc...

In the case you are referring (i.e. Cherrapunji), this is mostly due to a combination of Himalaya (topography forcing), Indian Ocean (source of humidity), Walker circulation and the strong tropical evaporation at those latitudes (among other things).